# How should the variables of an updating dictionary be converted to their appropriate types using an existing dictionary for reference?

Tags: python, dictionary, types

I've got a Flask website that updates a JSON file. The website gets a bunch of variables as a dictionary input and the idea is that each variable of this dictionary gets converted to its appropriate type by referencing the types of the existing dictionary that is loaded from the JSON file.

So, the existing configuration dictionary is loaded in a way like the following:

```
config = lock.load_JSON("config.json")
```

Then, the website gets input and puts it into a dictionary `input_config`. This input dictionary has values that are all strings. I need to convert these values to their appropriate types based on the existing configuration. Bearing in mind that I'm dealing with many more variables than shown below in the example, what'd be a nice way to do this?

```
config = {
    "a": True,
    "b": 1.05,
    "c": 30,
    "d": 9500,
    "e": 7000,
    "f": "maths",
    "g": True
}

input_config = {
    "a": "true",
    "b": "1.06",
    "c": "30",
    "d": "9500",
    "e": "4900",
    "f": "water",
    "g": "True"
}
```

I'm imagining something like the following:

```
for key, value in list(config.items()):
    try:
        config[key] = convert_type(input_config[key], type(value))
    except:
        print("error converting {value}".format(value = input_config[key]))
```

Comment: Store a dictionary of functions to convert the values.

Comment: Why do you have this input format? And why do some values say `"true"` and others say `"True"`?

Comment: The idea is that `input_config` holds the new values that should be used to update the old values in `config`. I included both "true" and "True" to illustrate different possible cases that must be accounted for (e.g. using `.lower() == "true"`).

Comment: Have you considered just storing the config as JSON or YAML instead of a list of strings? That may not be appropriate for your use case, but if it is, it solves your problem automatically.

Comment: @abarnert I am considering the step before saving. I need to ensure that the values that have been input by a user are appropriate before they can be used to update the existing configuration. That means that attempting to convert automatically to the appropriate type should throw an exception.

Comment: @BlandCorporation Often, expecting users to edit a YAML file isn’t harder than expecting them to learn your own idiosyncratic format that allows some oddities but not others in a way that’s probably hard to document beyond “read the code to see”. But “often” isn’t “always”, so maybe that isn’t true here; I can’t really tell from a vague description and a bunch of things named `a` and `b`, but you presumably know, so if you know my suggestion isn’t relevant... well, that’s why it’s a comment rather than an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `type()` for determining the types in the `config` dictionary then use that for parsing, you would just need to handle the special case of boolean since you obviously mean by "true" the boolean True not the string "true". Example:

Python 2.x

```
import types

for key in config.keys():
    if type(config[key]) == types.BooleanType:
        current = input_config[key].lower() == "true"
    else:
        current = type(config[key])(input_config[key])
```

Python 3.x

```
for key in config.keys():
    if type(config[key]) == bool:
        current = input_config[key].lower() == "true"
    else:
        current = type(config[key])(input_config[key])
```